# How to delete multiple files and directories of various locations in fedora 27

Tags: linux

I am using fedora 27. I installed wine to emulate some Windows applications. Unfortunately, it did not work as I expected and now I want to delete all the traces of wine from Fedora. I run the basic commands as yum remove wine. But the problem is that there still a lot of wine files and directories in Fedora. After run locate wine it gave me a long list of files from various locations. I attached a print-screen with the given results. Is there a way to delete all these files excepting the manual wiping file by file?[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text-only information; this does not add value, and indeed may make it harder for people to help you. Instead, copy-paste the information as text.

Comment: If you can run a command to list files, as you did above, then there are ways to delete this list of files. But I also don't think that `locate wine` is the proper way to find files installed with or because of Wine.

Answer (score 1):

The command `locate wine` is potentially dangerous if you use its output as arguments for a remove operation like with `rm`. The command `locate` lists all files having the substring "wine" in their path, which may or may not what you are actually looking for: It could remove the list of "old-wines.txt" you are keeping for your next party, but wouldn't delete "wn-config.ini" if that is part of the package you want to get rid of.

To see the list of installed files belonging to the RPM package "wine" use `rpm -ql wine`. The RPM subsystem distinguishes between package files and configuration, though. To list the latter, use `rpm -q --configfiles`. To delete both config files and package files, use the "erase" subcommand: `rpm -e`.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, a simple `rm /root/.local/share/mime/packages/x-wine-extension*` as root should work, but I'm assuming there are more files than shown. I would think that (with Wine installed) `sudo dnf remove wine` would work. Your ~/.wine folder won't be deleted, so you'll need to delete that manually.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how many files you are looking to delete nor if they all exist in the same directory or are scattered across various paths. But I will point out that if the number of files is too large, commands like ls & rm might fail to iterate over the entire list. In this case, you can use find to build a list of the files you are interested in and then using the -exec switch it can take action on each one individually. As a safety precaution, I recommend always using find to list the files before re-running the command with the -exec switch to make sure you know which files you are about to take action on.

For example, if you are aiming to remove only the x-wine-extension-*.xml files in /root/.local/share/mime/packages ... you would use find like this to list them:

```
find /root/.local/share/mime/packages -name x-wine-extension-\*.xml
```

And then to delete them you would use this:

```
find /root/.local/share/mime/packages -name x-wine-extension-\*.xml -exec rm {} \;
```